# MVC validating checkboxes - setting a checkbox to true when another checkbox gets checked

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I am starting to learn MVC. In WebForms you can easily do this....

```
If(checkbox.checked == true)
   checkbox2.checked = true
```

Heres my shot at MVC

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{ 
    if (ChkBox1)
    { 
        ChkBox2 = true
        yield return ChkBox2;
    } 
}
```

Of course this doesnt work.  Anybody have any ideas. It seems like a simple thing to do.

Comment: You can use the ViewBag to hold values that can be accessed by your view with Razor. But u don't have direct control over the html elements, that would not be a separation of concerns which is what MVC is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do this in javascript using a library like jQuery rather than server side.

```
$('chkbox1').change(function() { $('chkbox2').prop("checked",   $('chkbox1').prop("checked"))  });
```

Comment: Thanks...Thats probably the right answer.